# Troubles with UIView, animateWithDuration and beginFromCurrentState

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have a custom view that has to track the user's location. I put the following code in `touchesBegan`, as well as in `touchesMoved`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    cursorView.center = locationOfTouch;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

It seems fairly straightforward to me. I'd expect the view to always animate to the user's current location, even if that location is changed and the view is still animating (because of the beginFromCurrentState option).

Yet, each animation finishes completely. They don't 'transition' to the new animation, no they finish first, then they start the new animation.

I tried adding this line in `touchesMoved`:

```
[cursorView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Doesn't do anything. No animation is cancelled. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to do this with an animation, as opposed to just setting the center each time touchesMoved is called?

Comment: Yes; I don't want the view to "jump" to the location of the touch. I want it to smoothly animate it to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `[cursorView.layer removeAllAnimations];` you access the layer of the view but you have set the animation not to the layer but the view directly.
Try:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
cursorView.center = locationOfTouch;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and leave out the `removeAllAnimations` and it should transition from current state.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the iOS 4 block methods for this? I thought Apple recommended against using `beginAnimations:context:` since iOS 4?

Comment: I thought the same but even the syntax highlighting for "UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState" don't work for me, so I decided only use blocks for simple animations without fromCurrentState. (and if you decide to support older versions prior iOS4 you have to use this method)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a derivative of another question you asked that I just answered, but the same idea applies.

You don't need to use blocks to do this. Just wrap your setCenter in a UIView animation. Like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
cursorView.center = locationOfTouch;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Keep in mind that 0.2 seconds is pretty fast. It may *appear* to be "jumping" to the position. To confirm, set the duration to something like 2.0 seconds and see if it's animating.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the view should automatically animate with a default time of 0.25 seconds. That is what the manuals say, however, I'm currently on here because the manuals don't seem to be very accurate regarding animation.

Also, the beginAnimations call is being phased out, you might want to use a CATransaction instead