# Programmatically zoom in and out in iPhone: how can i set animation speed?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have an app where i would like to dynamically zoom in and out an imageView.

I use `[scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(x,y,z,k) animated:YES];` to zoom in but i would like the animation to be slower ... is there a way to set the animation speed?

Comment: This other [question][1] is the same and answered


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238567/any-way-of-changing-the-duration-of-zoomtorect-for-uiscrollview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587055/207616). You can set the animation duration to something like `1.0` second.

instead of:
`cursorView.center = locationOfTouch;`

you have to set:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

[scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(x,y,z,k) animated:NO]; // NO is necessary!

[UIView commitAnimations];
```