# How to Zoom Out and Zoom in on the perticular View in scroll view images

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

i am using this code for zooming this is perfect but i want zoomout after this zoomin.

```
CGFloat s = 3;
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(150, 300);
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, s, s);
CGFloat h = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat w = self.view.frame.size.width;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = tr;
    CGFloat cx = w/2-s*(p.x-w/2);
    CGFloat cy = h/2-s*(p.y-h/2);
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(cx, cy); //was: (w*s/2,h-h*s/2);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using hitTest and scroll view delegate method i.e, viewForZoomingInScrollView as follows.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return yourScrollView;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return yourImageView;
}
```

You can set the selected image in another scrollview and handle the zoom.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [self.imageView sizeToFit];

    //add this image view as subview of scroll view here and set content size accordingly.    

    CGFloat zoomScale = 1.0;

    if (self.imageView.frame.size.width < self.imageView.frame.size.height) {
        zoomScale = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width / self.imageView.frame.size.width);
    } else {
        zoomScale = (self.scrollView.frame.size.height / self.imageView.frame.size.height);
    }

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.imageView.frame.size];
    [self.scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:zoomScale];
    [self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1.0];
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:zoomScale];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((self.imageView.frame.size.width - self.scrollView.frame.size.width) / 2,
                                              (self.imageView.frame.size.height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height) / 2)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I did try this but this method never called - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

Comment: i am using scroll view in the scroll view is 128 images i wants click on the any Particular images then zoom in full view and again tab on the images the go to zoom out.

Comment: See this link. It might be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489906/programmatically-zoom-in-and-out-in-iphone-how-can-i-set-animation-speed

Comment: You can set the image in another scrollview when selected and then you can easily handle the zooming operations. I updated my answer. Once check it.

Comment: i did try this code zoom in is good but only first images not multiple images

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get you. Are you zooming only selected image in scroll view or the scroll view itself? If you wat zoom only selected image, follow the steps I provided. Take another scroll view and add an image view. Set ur selected image to that image view. And handle the zoom for that scroll view using zoomScale property. When clicked back, remove that scroll view from super view.

Comment: Or else if u want to zoom the scroll view which contains all your images, you can directly implement zoom functionality for the scroll view. And one important thing: No need of any calculations when using scroll view for zooming. It's the default functionality apple provided for scroll view.

Comment: I am zooming only selected images i am using your above code but how can i recognise which images i am selected and then called your method - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {    please suggest me i am totally struck.

Comment: i am added the UITapGestureRecognizer in the image view. but i cant get the images.

Comment: Its easy. Set tags to your image views in scroll view. In tap gesture's selector method you can access the selected image view based on tag. And get the image using imageView.image. If you are still struck, let me know. I will update my answer.